# Is this sentence "I withdrew from the school to prepare for transfer exams and transferred to another school" like the US English?

Tags: american-english, punctuation, phrase-choice

I wrote the sentence

"I withdrew from the school to prepare for transfer exams and transferred to another school"

but am unsure about if it is like the US English.

Comment: Your sentence is OK.  Perhaps punctuate so: `...exams, and then transferred...` You might want to explain what "transfer exams" are if you are writing for a US audience.

Comment: @TRomano: Thanks so much. In my country, universities are allowed to hold their own entrance exams for prospective students transferring from other schools. So how is such exam called in the US??

Comment: In the US, the tests are created and run by two for-profit corporations. Colleges and universities do not have their own examinations.  And, in general, there are no special tests for transfer students, though a particular faculty (e.g. music) may require an audition.

Comment: @TRomano: Ah, would you mind letting me know how to describe such tests in order to make US readers understand what I want to say? Thanks!

Comment: You have already done so above.  That one sentence should suffice.

Comment: Lest anyone disagree with my calling them "for-profit", they are indeed a business if they are non-profit in name: https://www.collegeboard.org/about/doing-business

Comment: @TRomano If I rewrite it as "I withdrew from the school for the preparation of transfer exams and then transferred to another school" would it be correct?

Answer (score 1):

PS "Like the US English" is not, actually, uhh, good US English.

I'd use the latter phrase.  Or something like "unsure if it sounds good to US English speakers."

:)